# About violence: abrupt; impulsive?

Tags: differences

Is it better to describe violence as "**abrupt violence**" or "**impulsive violence**"?

Or maybe neither, and there is a different, better word?

Thank you in advance for any help :)

Comment: 'Better' by whose standards? Did someone see violence break out without warning, or did someone act violently on a sudden impulse? You decide...

Comment: Your question cannot usefully be answered unless you offer some explanation the reason for your doubt.  Also, have you studied a dictionary to see if there are relevant difference nuances in these 'homoionynms'?  (The word exists in German but not in English:  I use it in the sense of similar, as opposed to the same, meaning.)  Could you also please explain the context of your question?

Comment: Thank you for your inputs, I will certainly clarify by providing the whole sentence:

"When you became as mute as a broken gong, you have attained peace, for there is none in you of impulsive/abrupt violence."

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to copy and paste your sentence from a comment here for reference: "When you became as mute as a broken gong, you have attained peace, for there is none in you of impulsive/abrupt violence."
"Impulsive" implies "done without thinking," which could mean that there's plenty of premeditated violence in the person.
"Abrupt" could mean violence that is sudden or over and done with very quickly. 
I don't think either is the correct word for what you mean. Now, do you mean no violence at all? If so, then I'd just say "violence" with no adjective. However, if you mean no unprovoked or unwarranted violence,  then maybe use one of those terms. Other choices are "irrational violence" or "wanton violence."

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue is collocation - as Kate Bunting has previously highlighted. 'Unprovoked violence' emphasises lack of provocation, 'mindless violence' highlights the absence of reason or purpose and 'gratuitous violence' could be spontaneous but with no reason except for the pleasure obtained by the perpetrator.

Answer (score -1):

I kinda find it funny that any new relationship is pretty much like a new pair of shoes where we need to walk around for sometime to find out if it is really comfortable.

Comment: Sorry, but we only want real answers. This is why I down-voted.